# Laravel 5.8 and datatable form validation

Tags: laravel, datatable, laravel-validation, yajra-datatable

I am using Laravel 5.8 and Yajra datatable package.

I have to build a dynamic form from the controller (it works well).

After submitting the form, when the validation fails, I want to display the old values in the form.

Display the form/datatable and validation work fine. I need the way to display the old values.

**Controller (build the form)** (just an excerpt as it works fine)

```
    if (request()->ajax())
    {
        return datatables()
                ->of($memberships)
                ->addIndexColumn()
                ->addColumn('amount', function($data) use ($membership, $amounts) {
                        $link = '<input type="text" id="membership_id[]" name="membership_id[]" value="' . $data->id . '" style="width:100px" class="form-control">';
                        $link .= '<input type="number" id="amount[]" name="amount[]" value="">';
                        return $link;
                    })
                ->rawColumns(['amount'])
                ->make(true);
    }

    return view('my_blade', compact('memberships', 'id'));
```

My question here is ***How to set the value attribute in the amount input field when the validation fails?***

**my_blade (display datatable form)** (just an excerpt as it works fine)

```
  @if (count($errors) > 0)
          <div class="alert alert-danger">
              <ul>
                  @foreach ($errors->all() as $error)
                      <li>{{ $error }}</li>
                  @endforeach
              </ul>
          </div>
      @endif

      <form method="POST" id="my_form" action="{{ route('my_submit_route') }}">
      @csrf

      <input type="text" id="id" name="id" value="{{ $id }}">

      <table id="my_datatable" class="table table-hover table-striped table-responsive">
        <thead class="crud-header">
            <tr>
              <th>No</th>
              <th>Name</th>
              <th>Description</th>
              <th>Status</th>
              <th>Amount</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>

        </tbody>
      </table>

      <div class="form-group row">
          <div class="col text-center">
              <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">
                  Save
              </button>
          </div>
      </div>

    </form>

    </div>
</div>

@endsection

@section('script')
    <script>

    $(document).ready(function() {

        /* Start Datatable  */
        $.ajaxSetup({
              headers: {
                  'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')
              }
          });

        $.noConflict();

        $('#my_datatable').DataTable({
            iDisplayLength: 100,

            serverSide: true,
            processing: true,

          ajax: {
            url: "{{ route('my_route', ['id' => $id]) }}",
            type: 'GET',
           },
          columnDefs: [
            {className: "dt-center", targets: "_all"}
          ],
          columns: [
            {data: 'DT_RowIndex', name: 'DT_RowIndex', orderable: false},
            {data: 'name', name: 'name'},
            {data: 'given_name', name: 'given_name'},
            {data: 'amount', name: 'amount'}
          ],
          order: [[1, 'desc']]
        });
        /* End Datatable  */

        });
      </script>
@endsection
```

My validation works fine. Just don't know how to display the old value when validation fails

My Controller (to process form submit)

```
    /* get the array of membership IDs */
    $membershipIDs = $request->membership_id;

    $validate_array = [];

    /* Loop through membership for validation */
    for($i = 0; $i < count($membershipIDs); $i++)
    {
        $validate_array['amount.'. $i] = 'sometimes|nullable|numeric|gte:0';
    }
    $validator =  Validator::make($request->all(), $validate_array);

    if ($validator->fails())
    {
      /* Get the array of amounts */
      $amounts = $request->amount;
      // How to manage here to return in the form and display the old values and the error message on the failed fields?      
    }
    else
    {
      //Process the form;
    }
```

My question: **How to manage in the controller to return in the form and display the old values and the error messages on the failed fields?**

I also use the following for validation, the validation works well but I cannot display the old values in the form after the validation fails.

```
$this->validate($request, $validate_array);
```

Thanks

Comment: So .... when the validator fails, there's a `return With` or a `back with` where you can pass the old values. Since you're passing it back through ajax, you need to handle it in the ajax part. It has a `success`, but you can also look at when `errors` come back

Comment: Yes I can redirect back by passing the old values. But need to do at least 2 things here. Get the old values (in the blade or forward to the controller?) and set in the input field (Ajax or in the controller?).

The point is that the input form is in the controller

<input type="number" id="amount[]" name="amount[]" value="">

How can I set the value field?

Answer (score 0):

Try this in your controller:

```
if ($validator->fails()) {
    return back()->withInput()->withErrors($validator);
}
```

Not sure if this also works in Laravel 5. But an alternate to this is:

```
if ($validator->fails()) {
    return redirect('post/create')
        ->withErrors($validator)
        ->withInput();
}
```

Which works in Laravel 5

Comment: This is ajax call, redirects are not suitable.

Comment: When I return back with data and errors, it is the blade with datatable.
How will I get the old values and how will I set them in the input fields?

Comment: Sorry, in an Ajax call you have to do it manually with javascript. Not sure if dataable also supports it, but it should look like $.ajax({
  url: "test.html",
  context: document.body
}).done(function() {
  $( this ).addClass( "done" );
});
You could also return an Json object https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/validation#working-with-error-messages https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/responses#json-responses